# How to get rectangle of the client area that is "free" of child windows

Tags: winapi

Is there an API or some well known procedure to get rectangle of the client are that is free of child windows?

For example, given below sample window I want to get rectangle as shown with red frame:

[image]

Comment: You could achieve this by getting all the child rectangles, and once you have that, find their bounding area, and then subtract the result from the entire client area.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, now I only have to figure out the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Winapi Rectangle Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/rectangle-functions

Comment: I'll use following to come out with formula (thanks both) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle

Comment: Why not simply put a blank Panel onto the window?  Then you can do whatever you need with the Panel.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is "Panel" or some link, I can't find any information.

Comment: The problem is underspecified. There are several rectangles that cover the area not occupied by child windows. There is no API call that would guess, that you mean the rectangle that spans across the top (as opposed to, say, the bottom, or the right-hand side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to useful comments that led me to [wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) of a bounding box, I have come out with the following function to calculate the minimum bounding box:

This function will calculate only the rectangle of a parent window that is occupied by child controls, to get unoccupied area the resultant rectangle needs to be ofset by entry client area rectange which depends on which portion of a window we want (so it's excluded from this answer)

**NOTE:** In this sample the `mChilds` variable is a `std::list` container to child controls and windows, and `mhWnd` is handle of a parent window that contains child controls.

```
D2D1_RECT_F ParentWindow::CalculateBoundingBox() const noexcept
{
    RECT client;
    D2D1_RECT_F result{ };
    GetClientRect(mhWnd, &client);

    if (mChilds.empty())
    {
        result = {
            .left = static_cast<float>(client.left),
            .top = static_cast<float>(client.top),
            .right = static_cast<float>(client.right),
            .bottom = static_cast<float>(client.bottom),
        };

        return result;
    }

    RECT window;
    GetWindowRect(mhWnd, &window);

    // Inverse of the parent screen coordinates
    std::swap(window.left, window.right);
    std::swap(window.top, window.bottom);

    for (auto& child : mChilds)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetWindowRect(child->GetHandle(), &rc);

        window.left = std::min(rc.left, window.left);
        window.top = std::min(rc.top, window.top);
        window.right = std::max(rc.right, window.right);
        window.bottom = std::max(rc.bottom, window.bottom);
    }

    POINT lt{
        .x = window.left,
        .y = window.top
    };

    POINT br{
        .x = window.right,
        .y = window.bottom
    };

    ScreenToClient(mhWnd, &lt);
    ScreenToClient(mhWnd, &br);

    result = {
        .left = static_cast<float>(lt.x),
        .top = static_cast<float>(lt.y),
        .right = static_cast<float>(br.x),
        .bottom = static_cast<float>(br.y),
    };

    return result;
}
```